Can a ZK-SNARK verifier run the trusted setup ceremony themselves, to avoid trusting third parties?
Most ZK-SNARK systems today (GROTH16, Plonk) require a trusted setup ceremony, in which the participants generate public and private parameters needed for the proof system to work. They're expected to securely erase the private parameters - Anyone who learns the private params can forge false proofs. They publish the public parameters and provers can use them to generate ZK proofs.
The literature always assumes a SNARK proof is intended to be published for many verifiers, but my use-case assumes only a single prover and verifier pair.
To avoid trusting a third party (e.g. the developer of the system) could the verifier perform the setup ceremony herself, and give the public parameters to the prover?

It doesn't matter if the verifier can forge proofs because she is the only agent who would accept such proofs.
The prover would not care which public parameters he uses, as long as the verifier accepts his proof.

Bonus question: Is there a simpler/easier way to create a 2-person ZK proof system for arbitrary computations?
